# MLE application with scipy.optimize in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, maximize, mle

I want to run simple Maximum Likelihood estimation in **python**. I want to try it by using `Scipy.optimize.minimize` in python. first I'll explain my model so you can figure out what is going to happen.

## Model Explanation

by MLE I want to estimate best value for 2 variables that maximizes my objective function!
and what are these variables and what is objective function? in picture bellow you can see my objective function! and my variables are **'Betaa'** and **'Kasi'**.
[image]
Now you find out what is my objective function and what are my variables(except `item` in objective function. I'll explain it! please keep reading). I want to implement MLE on dataset([click](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GvrwSp-oNOOOnzlJQkuXqNThrFfkUbXN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109141104836255235481&rtpof=true&sd=true) to download it from my google drive) that you can see in picture bellow:
[image]
it's pretty simple dataset! contains 501 rows and 1 column. now that you saw my data, it's time for explaining how MLE is gonna work on it!

### MLE

for each value in 'Loss' column, if the value is >160, i should calculate Target value by objective function(that i talked about it in first section) and if the value is <160, Target for that will be 0! see picture bellow then you will find out what I'm precisely talking about(also you'll find out what is `item` that i talked about it)!
[image]
MLE is gonna maximize summation of values in `Target` by finding best values for 'Betaa' and 'Kasi'!

### Code

so here is script that have been written for this purpose:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


My_DataFrame = pd.read_excel("<FILE_PATH_IN_YOUR_MACHINE>\\Losses.xlsx")
# i did put link of "Losses.xlsx" file in the model explaination section
# so you can download it from my google drive.
loss = My_DataFrame["Loss"]


def obj_function(x):
    k = x[0]
    b = x[1]

    target = np.array([])

    for iloss in loss:
        if iloss>160:
            t = np.log((1/b)*(1+(k*(iloss-160)/b)**((-1/k)-1)))
            target = np.append(target , t)
    
    # multiplied by (-1) so now we have maximization
    return -np.sum(target)


MLE_Model = minimize(obj_function , [0.7,20] )
print(MLE_Model)
```

and results of this code:

> t = np.log((1/b)*(1+(k*(iloss-160)/b)**((-1/k)-1)))
> fun: nan
> hess_inv: array([[1, 0],      [0, 1]])
> jac: array([nan, nan])
> message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
> nfev: 126
> nit: 1
> njev: 42
> status: 2
> success:**False**
> x: array([-1033.52630224,    25.32290945])

as you can see in results, `success: False` and optimal solution didn't found!
and now i don't know how to fix this issue and how to solve this MLE problem.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple runtime warnings due to overflow when evaluating `(...)**(-1/k - 1)`. Try to rewrite the objective function. Note also that this is more a constrained optimization problem since `log(x)` is only defined for positive x. Hence, you should set bounds for `k` and `b`.

Comment: @joni Thanks for your comment.
+ do you have idea for rewriting objective function?  

+ if you look at objective function precisely you find out that `...` in `log(...)` going to be negative if and only if `item < 160` ! and if you read my explanation precisely you figure out that I'm calculating `...` just for `item`s that are greater than 160! so there isn't any problem there and there's no need for constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, there are multiple runtime warnings due to overflow when evaluating the power. Looking closely, you can observe that your objective function is wrong. According to your picture, it should be

```
(1 + ( k*(iloss-160)/b) )**( (-1/k) - 1 )
```

instead of

```
(1 + ( k*(iloss-160)/b )**( (-1/k) - 1 )
```

Furthermore, you can avoid the calculation of the power and rewrite your objective by using the logarithm rules:

```
np.log(1/b) + ((-1/k)-1) * ( np.log(b+k*(iloss-160)) - np.log(b))
```

Last but not least, it's **highly** recommended to make yourself familiar with vectorized numpy operations to avoid loops:

```py
def obj_function(x):
    k, b = x

    iloss = loss[loss > 160.0]
    q = ((-1/k)-1)
    target = np.log(1/b) + q* ( np.log(b+k*(iloss-160)) - np.log(b))
    return -1.0*np.sum(target)
```

This gives me

```
In [9]: minimize(obj_function, x0=[0.7, 20])
Out[9]:
      fun: 108.20609317144068
 hess_inv: array([[ 1.03577269e-01, -2.40749570e+00],
       [-2.40749570e+00,  1.45377397e+02]])
      jac: array([ 9.53674316e-07, -9.53674316e-07])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 39
      nit: 9
     njev: 13
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 0.43624657, 32.53159127])
```

Comment: worked! I tested another dataset for this solution and verified result of optimization by optimizing in Microsoft EXCEL! I don't know how to appreciate for your help... it was huge help from you to me. Thanks for your advises. now I'm going to learn about **vectorized numpy operations** as you recommended. again, thanks for your great help.